# mysql sub query for find grade

Tags: mysql

I have tabel like this

```
+----+-------+------------+-------+
| No | NIK   | Nama       | Nilai |
+----+-------+------------+-------+
|  1 | 06001 | Syafruddin |    70 |
|  2 | 20000 | Maman      |    90 |
|  3 | 30000 | Linda      |    40 |
|  4 | 40000 | Tesa       |    71 |
+----+-------+------------+-------+
+-------------+-------+------------------+
| Range_Nilai | Point | Keterangan       |
+-------------+-------+------------------+
| 0 s/d 50    | E     | Tidak Lulus      |
| 51 s/d 80   | C     | Cukup            |
| 81 s/d 100  | A     | Sangat Memuaskan |
+-------------+-------+------------------+
```

and I want to get my results like this

[image]

but my results like this

[image]

when I try to change my query like this

```
THEN (SELECT b.Point,b.Keterangan FROM range_nilai b where b.Range_Nilai='0 s/d 50')
```

I got error 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)'

can someone help me pls?
this my [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42371c/2)

```
SELECT  a.*,
        ( CASE 
            WHEN a.nilai >=0 && a.Nilai<=50 
            THEN (SELECT Point FROM range_nilai where Range_Nilai='0 s/d 50')
            WHEN a.nilai >50 && a.Nilai<=80 
            THEN (SELECT Point FROM range_nilai where Range_Nilai='51 s/d 80')
            WHEN a.nilai >80 && a.Nilai<=100 
            THEN (SELECT Point FROM range_nilai where Range_Nilai='81 s/d 100')
            ELSE NULL
        END
         ) as Point,
        ( CASE 
            WHEN a.nilai >=0 && a.Nilai<=50 
            THEN (SELECT Keterangan FROM range_nilai where Range_Nilai='0 s/d 50')
            WHEN a.nilai >50 && a.Nilai<=80 
            THEN (SELECT Keterangan FROM range_nilai where Range_Nilai='51 s/d 80')
            WHEN a.nilai >80 && a.Nilai<=100 
            THEN (SELECT Keterangan FROM range_nilai where Range_Nilai='81 s/d 100')
            ELSE NULL
        END
         ) as Keterangan
FROM nilai a
```

this my last query I have.
may someone have more better query than me?

Comment: how is your data correllated? do you have any primary/foreign keys in any of your tables?

Comment: No I dont have. the instruction is just like that. I will update my correct query. But may someone has better answer than me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables and use the function [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) in the `ON` clause:

```
select n.*, r.Point, r.Keterangan
from nilai n inner join range_nilai r
on n.Nilai 
  between 
    substring_index(r.Range_Nilai, ' s/d ', 1)
    and
    substring_index(r.Range_Nilai, ' s/d ', -1)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ieBv6LdUtqSSZm6LynH4qP/1).
Results:

```
| No  | NIK   | Nama       | Nilai | Point | Keterangan       |
| --- | ----- | ---------- | ----- | ----- | ---------------- |
| 1   | 6001  | Syafruddin | 70    | C     | Cukup            |
| 2   | 20000 | Maman      | 90    | A     | Sangat Memuaskan |
| 3   | 30000 | Linda      | 40    | E     | Tidak Lulus      |
| 4   | 40000 | Tesa       | 71    | C     | Cukup            |
```